# The Things Stack | LoRaWAN AppEUI

Tags: iot, lorawan

I'm try to set up an end device on ([The Things Stack](https://www.thethingsindustries.com/stack/)) and I'm not sure about the AppEUI.

Now I have a problem: where to get that AppEUI? Should it be common to each end node (I guess it should)? Should I choose a random one or use same as DevEUI?

[End Device Setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F1Jnm.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The AppEUI is, as the name says, a unique identifier for an application you have registered in TTN. It is common to all devices that contribute to the application. The DevEUI on the other hand is unique to each device.

So: all devices that are on this application – same AppEUI. Every device – a unique, different DevEUI.